# Codigo que leia uma matriz de adjacencia e me retorne o anti-base da matriz - não retorna resultado

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calculadora de Anti-base</title>
  <style>
    /* Estilo para a fonte do textarea */
    textarea {
      font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Calculadora de Anti-base</h1>

  <!-- Entrada da matriz de adjacência -->
  <label for="matriz">Insira a matriz de adjacência:</label><br>
  <textarea id="matriz" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

  <!-- Botão para calcular a anti-base -->
  <button onclick="calcularAntiBase()">Calcular Anti-base</button><br><br>

  <!-- Exibição do resultado -->
  <div id="resultado"></div>

  <!-- Script JavaScript -->
  <script>
    function calcularAntiBase() {
      // Obtém a matriz de adjacência a partir da entrada do usuário
      const matrizStr = document.getElementById("matriz").value;
      const matrizLinhas = matrizStr.trim().split("\n");
      const matrizAdjacencia = matrizLinhas.map(linha => linha.trim().split(" ").map(num => parseInt(num)));

      // Calcula a anti-base da matriz de adjacência
      const antiBase = encontrarAntiBase(matrizAdjacencia);

      // Exibe o resultado
      const resultadoStr = "Anti-base: " + antiBase.join(", ");
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = resultadoStr;
    }

    function encontrarAntiBase(matrizAdjacencia) {
      const numLinhas = matrizAdjacencia.length;
      const numColunas = matrizAdjacencia[0].length;

      // Inicializa matriz aumentada com os mesmos valores da matriz de adjacência
      const matrizAumentada = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numLinhas; i++) {
        matrizAumentada[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < numColunas; j++) {
          matrizAumentada[i][j] = matrizAdjacencia[i][j];
        }
      }

      // Aplica eliminação gaussiana para obter matriz escalonada
      for (let k = 0; k < numLinhas; k++) {
        // Encontra a linha com o maior valor absoluto na coluna k
        let maxLinha = k;
        for (let i = k + 1; i < numLinhas; i++) {
          if (Math.abs(matrizAumentada[i][k]) > Math.abs(matrizAumentada[maxLinha][k])) {
            maxLinha = i;
          }
        }

        // Troca a linha atual com a linha com o maior valor absoluto na coluna k
        const temp = matrizAumentada[k];
        matrizAumentada[k] = matrizAumentada[maxLinha];
        matrizAumentada[maxLinha] = temp;

        // Aplica eliminação gaussiana para tornar zeros abaixo da diagonal principal
        // Aplica eliminação gaussiana para tornar zeros abaixo da diagonal principal
        for (let i = k + 1; i < numLinhas; i++) {
          const fator = matrizAumentada[i][k] / matrizAumentada[k][k];
          matrizAumentada[i][k] = 0;
          for (let j = k + 1; j < numColunas; j++) {
            matrizAumentada[i][j] = matrizAumentada[i][j] - fator * matrizAumentada[k][j];
          }
        }
      }

      // Encontra a anti-base da matriz de adjacência
      const antiBase = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numLinhas; i++) {
        let naoNulo = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < numColunas; j++) {
          if (matrizAumentada[i][j] !== 0) {
            naoNulo = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!naoNulo) {
          antiBase.push(i);
        }
      }
      return antiBase;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O codigo não me retorna o antibase e eu não faço mais a minina ideia dq pode esta acontecendo

Answer (score -1):

Para ler uma matriz de adjacência em JavaScript, podemos usar um formulário HTML para coletar os valores e, em seguida, manipular os dados usando JavaScript. Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
HTML:

<form>
  <label for="n">Número de vértices:</label>
  <input type="number" id="n" name="n" min="1" required><br>
  <label for="matrix">Matriz de adjacência:</label>
  <textarea id="matrix" name="matrix" required></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit">Calcular Anti-Base</button>
</form>

<p id="result"></p>
```

```
JavaScript:


function antiBase() {
  // Obter os dados do formulário
  const n = parseInt(document.getElementById('n').value);
  const matrixStr = document.getElementById('matrix').value.trim();
  
  // Converter a string da matriz em uma matriz 2D de números
  const matrix = matrixStr.split('\n').map(row => row.split(' ').map(Number));

  // Calcular a matriz anti-base
  const antiBase = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push((matrix[i][j] === 0 && i !== j) ? 1 : 0);
    }
    antiBase.push(row);
  }

  // Exibir o resultado
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = antiBase.map(row => row.join(' ')).join('\n');
}

// Adicionar um manipulador de eventos para o formulário
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Impedir que o formulário seja enviado
  antiBase(); // Calcular a matriz anti-base
});
```

Este código lê a matriz de adjacência a partir de uma área de texto no formulário HTML e, em seguida, usa um loop para calcular a matriz anti-base correspondente. Finalmente, exibe o resultado na página HTML. Note que, para impedir que o formulário seja enviado e recarregue a página, usamos event.preventDefault() no manipulador de eventos do formulário.